# elixir/phoenix запрос multipart/form-data в Postman

Tags: postman, elixir

подскажите, что я делаю не правильно. В общем виде задача стоит в том чтобы сохранять файлы локально как сделано в туториале ниже. Только там загрузка реализована через веб интерфейс, а мне надо прикрутить сторонний и посылать запросы через post get и тд. 
Туториал:
https://www.poeticoding.com/step-by-step-tutorial-to-build-a-phoenix-app-that-supports-user-uploads/
Исходник https://github.com/poeticoding/phoenix_uploads_articles

У меня не получается сформировать запрос в постман, я прицепляю файл, пробовал делать заголовок multipart/form-data или без него результат один.

```
no function clause matching in PoeticWeb.UploadController.create/2
```

Сначала ругался на csrf токен, поэтому я закомментировал 
 `plug :protect_from_forgery` 
Функция в контроллере выглядит так:

```
def create(conn, %{"upload" => %Plug.Upload{} = upload}) do
    case Documents.create_upload_from_plug_upload(upload) do
      {:ok, upload} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "file uploaded correctly")
        |> redirect(to: Routes.upload_path(conn, :index))

      {:error, reason} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:error, "error upload file: #{inspect(reason)}")
        |> redirect(to: Routes.upload_path(conn, :new))
    end
```

Кстати запрос который идет через форму, все равно содерджит в себе токен, не знаю виляет ли это на результат. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Итак как всегда стоило задать вопрос, сразу разобрался сам. 
Достаточно было добавить ключ upload в postman.